# Pipe and fork in unix |?

Tags: unix, pipe, fork

I was reading [what's a pipe in an operating system](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-pipe-in-an-operating-system) and there's something I don't understand.

Take a sequence of unix pipe-character-separated commands like

```
cat file | grep "something"
```

what happens when the pipe `|` is processed? I understand that a unix pipe is opened through the `pipe()` function, but I don't see how a 'fork' would take place here in any of the processes involved.

What happens and how is a fork involved (if any) ?

Comment: If confused about `fork`, don't confuse the issue with a pipe.  When you type `cat file` in your interactive shell, a fork happens.  You need to understand that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case there are actually *two* `fork` calls being made: One for the `cat` command and one for the `grep` command.

The `fork` calls are needed, because the only standard way in POSIX to execute programs is with the `exec` family of calls, and those *replace* the current process image with the image from the loaded program. And if the shell doesn't `fork` a new process for each command it executes, the first program run would replace the shell, and the shell will not exist anymore.

The pipe is set up so that the write-end of the pipe will be connected to standard output of the first child process (the `cat` command), and the read-end of the pipe will be connected to standard input of the second child process (the `grep` command).

All of this is happening behind the scenes in the shell.

Comment: Thanks, I read around and think I got that unix has no `CreateProcess` equivalent but the paradigm is rather `fork()` and (perhaps) `exec()`. Hence the series of `fork`s.